# Why am I getting 'No such module' and 'fatal error: module' errors when trying to build a React Native app on iOS simulator with Xcode 14.3?

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, xcode14.3

I've been trying to build a react-native (0.68.5) app via the ios simulator, which used to run ok when using Xcode 14.2, but now that I upgraded my Xcode version to 14.3 the app just won't compile. The errors I'm getting are:

1. fatal error: module 'React' in AST file .../React-Core.modulemap
2. No such module 'ExpoModulesCore'

I've created other projects from scratch and they work just fine, so I guess this is related to this project configuration.

I partially got the app to compile through Xcode by setting the Precompiled Bridging Header to No and using a Simulator with x86_64 architecture, but it doesn't connect to react-native cli, and when running react-native run-ios I keep getting the No such module 'ExpoModulesCore' error.

The steps I do to try to build the app are:

1. `yarn install`
2. `cd ios && pod install`
3. `yarn ios` (`react-native run-ios`)

I've tried to delete `node_modules` folder and `yarn clean cache` followed by a `yarn install` and it doesn't work.

I've also tried to do a `arch -x86_64 yarn ios` didn't work.

I've tried adding to my `Podfile` this line `config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"` and didn't work.

And now in Xcode 14.3 the option to open using Rosetta was deleted.

Update: Fixed this by uninstalling everything related to xcode and re installing Xcode 14.2, enabled open with rosetta option and re-do the steps mentioned on my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been reported issues with React Native and xCode 14.3. It's been released patches for React Native version range 69 -> 71, so you might need to upgrade your React Native.

See https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/12b5gn3/beware_of_xcode_143/ and https://twitter.com/Kelset/status/1642945598780485632?s=20

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed a problem with Xcode 14.3, I had to downgrade to Xcode 14.2

Comment: You're welcome! Please help out by marking the post as the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Apple didn't remove the option for Rosetta with Xcode 14.3. They only 'moved' the selection for this. It's not longer under Xcode's app info panel anymore. If you still wish to use Rosetta, you can make this selection by launching Xcode, then selecting "Product > Destination > Destination Architectures". Then on your targeted device you'll see a "(Rosetta)" indicator.